# NHibernate many-to-one with lazy false ever executes N queries

Tags: nhibernate, fetch

I want a list of Purchase searched with some criteria.
Purchase entity contains one Product.
This is the mappings:

```
<class name="Product" table="Products">
    <id name="Id">
        <generator class="identity"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="Name"></property>
    <many-to-one name="Brand" column="BrandId" lazy="false" fetch="join" />
    <many-to-one name="Category" column="CategoryId" lazy="false" fetch="join" />           
</class>

<class name="Shop" table="Shops">
    <id name="Id">
        <generator class="identity"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="Name"></property>
</class>

<class name="Purchase" table="Purchases" lazy="false">
    <id name="Id">
        <generator class="identity"></generator>
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="Product" column="ProductId" lazy="false" fetch="join" />
    <many-to-one name="Shop" column="ShopId" lazy="false" fetch="join" />
</class>
```

And this is the way as I perform the search:

```
string query = string.Format(@"
    select pc from Purchase as pc 
        inner join pc.Product as p
        left outer join p.Brand as b
    where
        {0} and {1}                     
        and 
        (
            (p.Name like '%{2}%')
            or (b.Name like '%{2}%')
        )                    
",  
    filters.From.HasValue ? "pc.Date >= " + SqlHelper.GetSqlDate(filters.From) : "1=1",
    filters.To.HasValue ? "pc.Date <= " + SqlHelper.GetSqlDate(filters.To) : "1=1",
    filters.Text);

var list = session.CreateQuery(query)
    .List<Purchase>();    //.Future<Purchase>().ToList();
```

return list;

(I didn't remove other filters on query just to "show" that a simple Get/Query/QueryOver is not possible (it is not readable as a SQL or HQL)

It can be improved... but the problem here is that this code produce 1 query for purchase list and N queries for Product plus M queries for Shop, for example 251 or 770 queries was executed instead of one.

I aspect that just one query was executed, because of `lazy="false"` on the `many-to-one` relation.

Why NHibernate make a query on Product (and on Shop) for every Purchase?
Ho can I change the mapping to obtain the execution of one query?

Thanks,
Alessandro

Comment: Did you try removing the `lazy="false"`?

Comment: I just try now... and I have an error reading purchase.Product  because Proxy session is closed. Without lazy="false", it is lazy="true", so proxy object was returned instead of objects. NHibernate.LazyInitializationException: Initializing[MyProject.Entities.Product#4]-Could not initialize proxy - no Session.

Comment: Add your solution as an answer and mark it as correct answer, so people could easily find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HQL does not respect `fetch="join"` (in the mapping). I explicit it adding `fetch` in the join:

```
select pc from Purchase as pc 
        inner join **fetch** pc.Product as p
        left outer join **fetch** p.Brand as b
```

... and it works: only one query is executed.